# Which Macs support macOS_ReadWriteTextureTier2?

Tags: macos, metal

I'd like to use read-write textures in `R16Float` format. Neither my Late 2013 MacBook Pro or Late 2014 Mac Mini support the `macOS_ReadWriteTextureTier2` which would enable this.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH14 under "Tier 2 Pixel Formats"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the local Apple Store and ran a little test program on each Mac. All the discrete GPUs on current Macs (iMac, Mac Pro, MacBook Pro as of October 2017) support Tier 2. The integrated GPUs (Intel) do not.